# How to create a blog using php or xml

Tags: php, xml, blogs, blogger

Hi I want to create a simple blogger system only with anyone can make posts, comment on posts but only admin can delete or modify the posts.

Can someone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with ? What do you have so far ? What problems are you facing ?

Comment: I want a $100,000 bonus, but it just doesn't seem to be in the cards.

Answer (score 4):

or create a account on blogger.com

Answer (score 2):

You could install [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/download/) on your server